# Building static executable TMUX on Linux

Tags: compilation, executable, tmux

I have modified the tmux source code and need to compile it as a static executable file to be able to transfer it in different linux distributions. How to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Instructions on building and installing tmux are here: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Installing

You can configure for a static build with `--enable-static`.

Comment: This answer does not solve the whole problem. On the internet I found a script that creates static tmux https://gist.github.com/tessus/5e118d44261a6ab2f198 The build is successful from the official repository, but there is an error with our version. Tmux works on shared compilation. I use tmux 3.2 rc, ncurses 6.2, libevent 2.1.11 and Centos 7 for compilation.

Comment: You may also reference this github project: https://github.com/mjakob-gh/build-static-tmux